# Maintaining the Order in the list in next iteration

Tags: c#, list

I am getting a List from a webserver and passing this data, However I am trying to maintain the order in which I pass the items.

For example I am getting a List of names

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
```

I assign an Id to them

```
1. Name1
2. Name2
3. Name3
```

and pass this list further.

In next call, I get this list again and I need to know In which order I sent them last time.  Now the issue is that next time when we get this list, it can come in any order, even it can have duplicates lets say

```
Name2
Name3
Name4
Name2
```

so I here I need to know what ID I assigned to it last time, so it should become ( assign new Ids to the new items)

```
2. Name2
3. Name3
1. Name4
4. Name2
```

and so on..

I thought of having a Dictionary and store it first time, when I get this list next time, find that "Name", get that ID and assign it to the Name, Something like this

```
  var searchName = "Name1";
  var index = GetNameIndex(searchName);
  if (index != 0)
  {
     nameIndex = index;
  }
  else
  {
     _namePositionDictionary.Add(++nameIndex, searchName );
  }


  int GetNameIndex(string searchName)
  {
     return (from a in _namePositionDictionary where a.Value == searchName select a.Key).FirstOrDefault();
  }
```

But My whole Logic failed, when I got duplicates in my first list

```
Name1
Name2
Name1 <-- This one didn't got added to the list at all
```

Comment: Your dictionary contains Dictionary<string,string> ?

Comment: @vinodh, It is Dictionary<int,string>, but i can change to any type if required.

Comment: I usually just create a custom class with an ID, name, and static list.  I can then sort the List easily by ID so I always will have the same order.

Comment: You might get by with using result of `GetHashCode()` as your id. That way you won't have to maintain any state. But it depends on what is in your list items and you may need to override it to be reliable.

Comment: finding the last dictionary key value _namePositionDictionary.Keys.Last(); and increment key value and add the new item. I updated the answer in fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the fiddle for your answer with `Dictionary<int,string>` . Please find the link.If you are using int as key we are not unable to ignore sequence so maximun key is good solution for this.Hope it will help to you.

if the int key value is sequential order you can use

```
var increKey=Dictionary.Keys.Last();
```

Last() method used to find the key and you can increment the key value like

```
 `MyDictionary.add(increKey++,"values");`
```

if there is no sequence in keys just try to find the maximum of key values and update your dictionary.

```
var maxValue=_namePositionDictionary.Keys.Max();
MyDictionary.add(maxValue++,"values");
```

Changes in your code :

```
var searchName = "Name1";
var index = GetNameIndex(searchName);
if (index != 0)
{
 nameIndex = index; // if you want to add duplication data add else statements here
}
else
{
   var maxValue=_namePositionDictionary.Keys.Max();
  Console.WriteLine("Max Key Value:"+maxValue);
  //var last = _namePositionDictionary.Keys.Last(); If there is no sorted order
  var val1=maxValue+1;
  Console.WriteLine(val1);
 _namePositionDictionary.Add(val1, searchName );

}


int GetNameIndex(string searchName)
{
 return (from a in _namePositionDictionary where a.Value == searchName    select a.Key).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

[ADDED Answer in Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rZB2Il)